# Nginx 301 redirect from oldsite to newsite

Tags: magento, nginx, redirect, http-status-code-301

Below URLs and their header status code. Please note that redirection is happening. But in some cases I see 301 in header and some cases I am not able to see.

```
https://www.oldsite.com -> 301 found in header
https://oldsite.com -> 301 found in header
http://www.oldsite.com -> No 301 found in header
http://oldsite.com -> No 301 found in header

https://www.newsite.com - Target site
https://newsite.com -> 302 found in header
http://www.newsite.com -> No 301 found in header
http://newsite.com -> No 301 found in header
```

I have four configuration stated below. Is there anything wrong with any of these configurations. Please note that this is a magento site.

oldsite.com.nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen      ipaddress:80;
    server_name oldsite.com www.oldsite.com;
    root        /home/oldsite/web/oldsite.com/public_html;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
 return 301 https://www.newsite.com$request_uri; 
}
    include     /home/oldsite/conf/web/nginx.oldsite.com.conf*;
}
```

oldsite.com.nginx.ssl.conf

```
server {
    listen      ipaddress:443;
    server_name oldsite.com www.oldsite.com;
    root        /home/oldsite/web/oldsite.com/public_html;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;

    ssl         on;
    ssl_certificate      /home/oldsite/conf/web/ssl.oldsite.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/oldsite/conf/web/ssl.oldsite.com.key;

location / {
 return 301 https://www.newsite.com$request_uri; 
}
```

newsite.com.nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen      ipaddress:80;
return 301 https://www.newsite.com$request_uri; 
    server_name newsite.com www.newsite.com;

    root        /home/newsite/web/newsite.com/public_html/pub;
    index       index.php;
    autoindex   off;
    charset     UTF-8;
    error_page  404 403 = /errors/404.php;
    add_header  "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";

}
```

newsite.com.nginx.ssl.conf

```
server {
    listen      ipaddress:443 http2;
    server_name newsite.com www.newsite.com;

    root        /home/newsite/web/newsite.com/public_html/pub;
    index       index.php;
    autoindex   off;
    charset     UTF-8;
    error_page  404 403 = /errors/404.php;
    add_header  "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";

    ssl         on;
    ssl_certificate      /home/newsite/conf/web/ssl.newsite.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/newsite/conf/web/ssl.newsite.com.key;

}
```

Comment: What does "No 301 found in header" mean?

Comment: Response header containing status code.

Comment: The first line of an http response is the status line which always includes a status code. Use `curl -I` to test each server and show those which deviate from your expectation.

Comment: Perfect. I see 301 for 6 URLs except https://newsite.com which displays a temporary redirect. How can I convert this into a permanent one?

Comment: I cannot see how `https://newsite.com` is redirected - it would be handled by the last configuration block, which appears to be incomplete. Is it handled by your application?

Comment: Yes. Magento has that option. How can I handle this in nginx please?

Comment: You could split that last server block into two, one for each `server_name`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate in the answer section please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle `example.com` and `www.example.com` differently, you should split your existing `server` block into two, and place the desired `return` statement into one of them.

For example:

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate      /home/newsite/conf/web/ssl.newsite.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/newsite/conf/web/ssl.newsite.com.key;

    return 301 https://www.newsite.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate      /home/newsite/conf/web/ssl.newsite.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/newsite/conf/web/ssl.newsite.com.key;

    root        /home/newsite/web/newsite.com/public_html/pub;
    index       index.php;
    autoindex   off;
    charset     UTF-8;
    error_page  404 403 = /errors/404.php;
    add_header  "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";

    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome. It works. From SEO point of view is this setup correct or the earlier with 302. Just curious

Comment: Sorry, can't help with SEO.